# Is angular. is enough for front end without any template engine?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

In my new project I prefer to use Angular.js I have an exposure with Thmyleaf, Velocity and spring frameworks. Can I Completely replace  Thymleaf or Jsp with Angular.js or do I still need to use JSP or Thymleaf?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this framework : [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/). It uses Spring Boot + Spring MVC REST + Maven + AngularJS + Bootstrap + front-end tools like Yeoman. See also this [presentation](http://jhipster.github.io/presentation/#/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example JSP or Thymeleaf if you want to render your pages on the server-side and then just have Angular.js manage some small part of those pages on the client-side.

But if you want to have your front-end completely client-side, you shouldn't need JSP, Thymeleaf or any other server-side templating technology. Serving static HTML files which contain your HTML/Angular markup should be sufficient in that case.